# Class's Integer use in Rect's width

Tags: java, class, scope, graphics2d

Soo, I tried to write hp interface in game, width rect will have hp*20 and 20 hight. It'll be a game with classes and "gifs" (my first normal game:D).How to write width rect with Tim.hp*20 ? If you're read this and help, good luck in codding!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    myFrame window = new myFrame();

    warior Tim = new warior();
    Tim.hp=100;
}

}

class myFrame extends JFrame
{
public myFrame()
{
    myPanel panel = new myPanel();
    Container cont = getContentPane();
    cont.add(panel);
    setBounds(0,0,1900,1000);
    setVisible(true);
}
}

 class myPanel extends JPanel
{

private Image gif1;
private Image gif2;

private int x1=850,y1=300;
private int x2=550,y2=300;
private int n=1;
private int n2=1;

public myPanel()
{
    setFocusable(true);

        Timer nt = new Timer(1000,new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try
                {
                    gif1=ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Тима\\Desktop\\"+ n +".solider.png"));
                    n++; 
                    System.out.println(n);
                    if (n>=3) n=1;
                    System.out.println(n);

                    gif2=ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Тима\\Desktop\\"+ n2 +".mutant.png"));
                    n2++; 
                    System.out.println(n2);
                    if (n2>=3) n2=1;
                    System.out.println(n2);
                }
                catch (Exception exp) {}
                repaint();
            }
        });
        nt.start();
    } 

public void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
{
    gr.clearRect(x1, y1, gif1.getWidth(null), gif1.getHeight(null));
    gr.drawImage(gif1, x1, y1, null);
    gr.clearRect(x2, y2, gif2.getWidth(null), gif2.getHeight(null));
    gr.drawImage(gif2, x2, y2, null);
    gr.fillRect(10, 800, 20, hp*20); //there is an error
}
}

class warior
{
int hp;
}
```

Comment: @Daniel Alder, yes.. How to write width rect with Tim.hp*20 ?

Comment: What happens? 1) The rect on the wrong place 2) you have a runtime error 3) you have a compile error. Don't expect that 200 people execute your code just for finding out what's not working on your code

Comment: @Daniel Alder, The rect will have 2000 width (Tim.hp=100, after 100*20 in rects width) but rect have 20 width

Comment: That's not possoble: When I try to compile the code, I see the error: `p cannot be resolved to a variable`. *This code doesn't draw anything on the screen.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously have a compile error (`hp cannot be resolved to a variable`) because you don't know how to access field `hp` of the foreign object `warior` (correct spelling: warrior?).

You create an instance of `warior` in the `main` function but don't keep the reference of it. Everything you set on tim will be only accessible on places where you have access to `tim`. In your code, that's *only* in `main()`

Depending on what's the function of `hp` and `warior`, you have the following options:

1. Declare `int hp` static and access it using `warior.hp` (not good style)
2. Use the [singleton pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html) for the class `warior`
3. Add a parameter `warior tim` for `myFrame()`, store it there in an instance field and use it in the function `paintComponent()`

In 1. and 2. you will only have one instance of the variable (1.) or the object (2.)

In 3., you can have several instances of `warior` but have to keep track of which object you are using. This is the usual use case.

Example for 3.:

```
--- orig    2015-11-20 14:23:05.221578051 +0100
+++ mod 2015-11-20 14:24:46.691333378 +0100
@@ -12,19 +12,20 @@

 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
-    myFrame window = new myFrame();
-
     warior Tim = new warior();
     Tim.hp=100;
+
+    myFrame window = new myFrame(Tim);
+
 }

 }

 class myFrame extends JFrame
 {
-public myFrame()
+public myFrame(warior tim)
 {
-    myPanel panel = new myPanel();
+    myPanel panel = new myPanel(tim);
     Container cont = getContentPane();
     cont.add(panel);
     setBounds(0,0,1900,1000);
@@ -42,9 +43,12 @@
 private int x2=550,y2=300;
 private int n=1;
 private int n2=1;
+private final warior tim;

-public myPanel()
+public myPanel(warior tim)
 {
+    this.tim = tim;
+
     setFocusable(true);

         Timer nt = new Timer(1000,new ActionListener()
@@ -78,7 +82,7 @@
     gr.drawImage(gif1, x1, y1, null);
     gr.clearRect(x2, y2, gif2.getWidth(null), gif2.getHeight(null));
     gr.drawImage(gif2, x2, y2, null);
-    gr.fillRect(10, 800, 20, hp*20); //there is an error
+    gr.fillRect(10, 800, 20, tim.hp*20); //there is an error
 }
 }
```

Btw: according to [java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) you should use lowercase for variables (`tim` instead of `Tim`) and CamelCase for classes (`Warrior` instead of `warior`)

Comment: Can you give an example?